# How to sum values when the sum range is not constant across rows?

Tags: excel

I've got somewhat of a complicated one here which I've been wracking my brain over and searching the web and youtube, etc.  Here's the challenge:

Let's say I have a workbook with 2 worksheets structured like so:

**Sheet 1**

```
          A              B           C           D 
|------------------------------------------------------|
|                  |    3/1    |    3/2    |    3/5    |
|------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|                  | Est | Act | Est | Act | Est | Act |
|------------------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
| Fred             |  2  |  5  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  2  |
|------------------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
| Jim              |  6  |  2  |  1  |  2  |  1  |  1  |
|------------------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
| Weekly Billable  |  8  |  7  |  3  |  5  |  5  |  3  |   
|------------------------------------------------------|
```

**Sheet 2**

```
         A                B          C           D 
|------------------------------------------------------|
|                  |    3/1    |    3/2    |    3/5    |
|------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|                  | Est | Act | Est | Act | Est | Act |
|------------------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
| Fred             |  2  |  5  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  2  |
|------------------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
| Jim              |  2  |  2  |  5  |  2  |  1  |  1  |
|------------------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
| Jane             |  2  |  1  |  1  |  1  |  1  |  1  |   
|------------------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
| Weekly Billable  |  4  |  8  |  8  |  6  |  6  |  4  |   
|------------------------------------------------------|
```

Next I have a sheet where I want to grab the Weekly Billable values for the given week from each sheet.  If at all possible, I'd like to have the ability to copy formulas down or across since the folks using this sheet have no clue about Excel.  (I don't consider myself good at it either - just a proud nerd who likes it)

**Totals Sheet**

```
|------------------------------------|
|                  | 3/1 | 3/2 | 3/5 |
|------------------|-----|-----|-----|
|                  |  WB |  WB |  WB |
|------------------|-----|-----|-----|
| Sheet 1          |  7  |  5  |  3  |
|------------------|-----|-----|-----|
| Sheet 2          |  8  |  6  |  4  |
|------------------|-----|-----|-----|
```

So far, I've been able to figure out how to use INDIRECT to reference the different sheets.  The trouble I'm having is the fact that the data from each sheet doesn't occur in the same place because the names on Sheet 1 and Sheet 2 can expand down, which makes the Weekly Billable row expand down as well.

So, as of now, I'm thinking I need to figure out a formula which will find the text "Weekly Billable" and then use SUM(IF...) or SUMIFS(...) or SUMPRODUCT(...) or something to get the right criteria to match the dates between the totals sheet and both Sheet 1 and Sheet 2, as well as to pull only the "Act" values from the Weekly Billable columns from Sheet 1 and Sheet 2.

I hope this is clear; I've tried to be as thorough as possible.  Thanks very much for reading and I appreciate any and all help with this.

Here's an example workbook I've put together to show what I'm trying to do.  I've gone ahead and put the values in manually to the Utilization Sheet.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/d4r6o41mvekwajl/Utilization%20Example.xlsm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this formulas.

1) for "Weekly Billable" column:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("'" & $A7 & "'!" & "$3:$30"),
           MATCH("Weekly Billable",INDIRECT("'" & $A7 & "'!" & "$D:$D"),0)-2,
           MATCH(F$4,INDIRECT("'" & $A7 & "'!" & "$4:$4"),0)+1)
```

2) for "Weekly Total Effort" column:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("'" & $A7 & "'!" & "$3:$30"),
           MATCH("Weekly Total Effort",INDIRECT("'" & $A7 & "'!" & "$D:$D"),0)-2,
           MATCH(F$4,INDIRECT("'" & $A7 & "'!" & "$4:$4"),0)+1)
```

Here is [**test workbook**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5rqzv6vlygd6ucn/Utilization%20Example.xlsm)

I highlighted formulas with yellow:

[image]

Comment: I KNEW it had to be something with INDEX and MATCH!  Good to know I was on the right track. Thanks, simoco, I'll give this a try.  Really appreciate the answer.

Comment: One other quick thing I'm noticing.  When I sum my Bill and TE totals across row 6, I get a #REF error, but I notice you don't have that problem and I'm not sure why.  Originally, I thought it could be because I had a hidden row, but that doesn't seem to make a difference.  Do you happen to have any thoughts on what could cause that?  Thanks again for the help in any case!

Comment: you get `#REF` if sheet name from column `A` doesn't exist. Maybe you have empty cell in column A for hidden row, or simple typo in sheet name. In that case `INDEX(INDIRECT("'" & $A7 & "'!" & "$3:$30")` can't find thouse address and return `#REF!`. You can handle it using `=IFERROR(INDEX(...),0)`

Comment: Got it, I just came to that conclusion, too.  Thanks again!